# How to generate panorama without OpenCV on android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

Now I am going to create an android app with a feature which could generate panorama from several input pictures.

I searched relative topics. In most of these topics guys talked about how to do it by using 'stitching module' of OpenCV4Android.
And there is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020631/panorama-stitching-with-android-camera-source-code) in which MosaicFrameProcessor is used to generate a mosaic pic, but as the author said, the output is not good enough, because this class just appends pixel data directly without feature recognitions or warp operations.

Is there any api for image stiching in andoird source code without OpenCV?